# Code to check all win combinations in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm writing a Tic Tac Toe program in c#, and to check whether a player wins I currently have 16 `if` statements (8 options for both `x` and `o`). (The buttons are numbered like phone dialpad).

Short example:

```
if (button1.Text == "X" && button2.Text == "X" && button3.Text=="X")//horizontal top X
{
    MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! X wins!", "Winner!");
}

if (button1.Text == "O" && button2.Text == "O" && button3.Text == "O")//horizontal top O
{     
    MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! O wins!", "Winner!");                
}

if (button4.Text == "X" && button5.Text == "X" && button6.Text == "X")//horizontal middle X
{
    MessagBox.Show("Congratulations! X wins!");
}

if (button4.Text == "O" && button5.Text == "O" && button6.Text == "O")//horizontal middle O
{
    MesageBox.Show("Congratulations! O wins!", "Winner!");                
}
```

Is there a way to say "Next button" / button index?, because then I can do:

```
if (button.Text==NextButton.Text==NextButton.Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! X wins!", "Winner!");
}
```

or:

```
if (button[i].Text=="X" && button[i++].Text=="X" && button[i+=2].Text=="X")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
if (button1.Text == button2.Text && button2.Text == button3.Text)
   MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! " +button1.Text +" wins!", "Winner!");
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could create a 3x3 array of buttons, then you could access them using your indexing method ie `button[row,column]`.